# Internet connection monitoring program

Tags: monitoring, internet

My internet connection os very unstable. Sometimes it has quick downloading speed, but mostly looses around 40% of packages, and the ping is around 900 ms.

I would like to download a program that would monitor the status of my internet connection, so after a while I can show the exact output to my provider as a proof. Because when you call the services, the problem is already gone.

Can you recomend me a program that would do such a thing in a background, later providing files with data of exact parameters of my connection?

Thanks :)

Comment: In order to have us help you, you need to provide basic information, such as for which operating system(s) people are to provide recommendations, and whether you are looking for recommendations for gratis or commercial software.  Please help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [WinMTR](http://winmtr.net/how-to/) if you are using Windows and [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) otherwise.

While they do not measure connection speed, these programs combine `ping` and `traceroute`, so you can see dropped packets and where they get dropped. You can also save a log after running it for a while.

Note that you will need to decide what host to ping. [Google's DNS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) at 8.8.8.8 is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

One that I have seen used successfully for this sort of thing was [python](https://www.python.org/) + [pyspeedtest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspeedtest) to periodically perform the speed test and [python twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/) to automatically post the results to twitter.

You could also consider [google speedtest chart](https://github.com/frdmn/google-speedtest-chart) which automatically tests your connection and collates the results to a Google Chart, *(You do **need** to follow the step by step guide provided in the readme files)*.

The above is Free, Gratis & Open Source and is cross-platform so will work anywhere, assuming a recent installation of python.

Answer (score 0):

I use a piece of software called [BitMeter](https://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros) OS to monitor my internet speeds, and it works very well.

It runs in the background at all times, and the data can be accessed via a web interface in your browser.

Features include:

- Real-time network speed graph
- A stopwatch to calculate the average, minimum and maxiumum speed of upload/download over a period of time, and the total data downloaded/uploaded
- A history view, showing connection speed usage over longer periods of time (minutes, hours, days). This data can also be exported as CSV.
- A query view, to query your data usage between a specified set of dates
- Customisable alerts to tell you when you have used a certain amount of data
- A calculator to determine how long it will take to download something, or how much you can download in a specified period of time
- Adjustable settings for units, colors etc.
- and more

BitMeter OS is both free and [open source](https://github.com/codebox/bitmeteros) (GPL-3.0). It can be downloaded from [here](https://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros).