# Software to quickly determine the causes of breaks Internet connection or bad internet connection

Tags: gratis, networking, windows-10, network-monitor, connection-speed

### 1. Summary

I often occur breaks Internet connection or bad Internet connection. I don't find program, which would help fast determine the cause of breaks Internet connection.

---

### 2. Expected behavior

I don't have Internet Connection or I have bad connection. I run program → I see result in my monitor, for example:

- Most likely, the problem is in your router. Please, to make `$actions$`. See `$additional information$`.
- Most likely, the problem is in your provider. Please, to make `$actions$`. See `$additional information$`.

#### 1. Requirements

- Gratis,
- Windows 10 compatible.

#### 2. Desirable requirements

- Easy to use for nonspecialists.

---

### 3. Do not offer

Yes, I know about `ping`, `tracert`, `ipconfig`, `netstat` utilities and about [**pyspeedtest**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/36654/23324) Python package. I want identify causes more quickly.

Comment: I assume you also don't want the Windows built-in network connection diagnosis

Comment: What does "more quickly" mean? How long do those programs take and what duration is acceptable? A ping -n 1 on Windows takes 1 second to complete. So, that's too slow, right? How many milliseconds do you need? I can't even measure the time of `ipconfig`, it's just too fast (maybe 100 ms). It seems to me that it takes longer to click on whatever program to start it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, **1)** I try to use built-in network connection diagnosis, but I don't get reasons of my bad connections. If it's possible, it would be nice, if someone tell me about it. // **2)** I print in my command line `ping` command, I get result. But I don't get reason of my bad connection. I need print other commands, and it may takes a lot of time. // Thanks.